# Is every continuous map from a path-connected space to itself homotopic to the identity?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, path-connected

Let $X$ be a path-connected topological space and $f : X → X$ a continuous map.

We know that any two paths $[0, 1] → X$ are homotopic. Note that, for some path $\sigma$ in $X$, $f ∘ \sigma$ is another path in $X$. Hence, they are homotopic: $f ∘ \sigma \sim \text{id}_X ∘ \sigma$. From this, can we somehow derive that actually $f \sim \text{id}_X$?

(EDIT: Before anyone starts to argue with homology, I actually want to *use* this to prove that $f_* = \text{id}_{H_0(X)}$.)

Comment: "We know that any two path in  are path homotopic." We do? What other assumptions are you making about $X$? There are lots of path-connected spaces with more than one path-homotopy class!

Comment: Sorry! Not path-homotopic! But simply homotopic, right? As maps $[0, 1] → X$? Is my edited question well-defined now?

Comment: Consider cases where $X$ is a circle.

Comment: Homotopy theory would be profoundly uninteresting if the answer to your question were yes. Fortunately, if isn't. E.g., consider the constant map $z \mapsto 1$ from $\Bbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ to itself. Nonetheless, what you want to prove about $H_0(X)$ is true, which you can prove by considering what $H_0$ does to the sequence of mappings $* \to X \to *$, where $*$ is any point of $X$ and the first mapping is the inclusion.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll leave this route of inquiry then, thanks for saving me time! EDIT: Thanks for the added hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to show that any two maps to $X$ are homotopic. The argument: we can join $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by a path, and then move along these paths for every $x$ to create the homotopy. There are two problems: there may not be a unique path. OK, so you need to make a choice. Now, you are arguing: I can choose for every $x$, $y$ in $X$ a path from $x$ to $y$ in a continuous way. That again may not work.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider the circle $X = S^1$. No constant map on $S^1$ is homotopic to the identity.